# disable php error notification

Tags: php, .htaccess

My Upload Folder is being exploited by people trying to hack my site ,i add an htaccess with code for disabling php engine on it ..

but it leaves white notification that the engine is turned off in that directory , i try using php.ini to remove this notification but it didnt work

```
ERROR :PHP ENGINE DISABLED
```

my ini file

```
display_startup_errors = Off
display_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
docref_root = 0
docref_ext = 0
```

Also Im sorry for asking two question what is the correct code for removing html/htm filetype or the best aproach to secure my upload dir?

Previously im using filematch for PHP but apparently my webhost is able to execute file such as file.php.jpg, or nameless extention

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(php|php3?|phtml|html|htm)$">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```

if there a file.pl,file.py,file.ph it still get executed or html file with random extention such as file.test still serve as html pages

Comment: Restart your server after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
# PHP error handling for development servers
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
php_value error_log /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
php_value error_reporting -1
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
```

and as a last shot that I've not seen anywhere else

```
 error_reporting = 0
```

Then to make it secure :

> In php.ini Set upload_tmp_dir to a folder that is:
>       outside the document root of your web site
>       not readable or writable by any other system users

[More infos](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/upload_tmp_dir.html)

use [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move files outside your document tree, provided that you have the right permissions to access it yourself. And don't forget to rename that uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 
error_reporting(0); // Disable all errors.